# I want to convert a set of code to a package so user can't able to see the code , but they are able to run the file

Tags: python, package, software-design

I am little bit confuse how to do this in python.in my code i want users can able to run the main.py file, without seeing the code of that file.

Comment: Python is an interpreted language. If your main.py doesn't contain plain text (Python code) then the *python* executable won't be able to run it. There are several mechanisms available for Python code obfuscation. Google will be your friend in this case

Answer (score 1):

Use the PyInstaller library (Docs - https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable) to package your code, and you can use the command below for windows -

```
pyinstaller sourcecode.py --onefile
```

Although this will not retain source code, it will create compiled python scripts (.pyc files) which could be decoded to reveal your source code. One way to obfuscate that is to use cython to compile some of your code to convert python to C, and compile C into machine language.

Comment: i will try this one also but ,
i have files structure like this Create_table   
 Parser       Similarity
database.db       main.py      
db_connection.py   README.md    Test Suite